# Is there an alternative to the "filter_var" function in php when using HHVM?

Tags: php, hhvm

I have been recently playing around with HHVM. Went through a lot of trouble getting it to work on my computer. I know that not all PHP functions are available. As a test, I am writing a new website using it instead of using my current code. I ran into a problem when trying to use

```
filter_var($var,FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

From the error.log file, it turns out that this function is undefined. Is the filter_var function not available for use in HHVM or am I just doing something wrong here. I like to keep things DRY, this would mean I have to do a lot more validation than I expected.

Comment: This appears to be standard equipment on php => 5.2 based on http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php .  What version you running?

Comment: But I am using HHVM(HipHop Virtual Machine), I don't think my PHP version really makes a difference because my code is not interpreted by the PHP interpreter. (Or at least that's what I think.)

Comment: Only it looks like filter_var is on the short list of features that facebook didn't port over to HHVM (because of complexity)/ http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.linguistics.wikipedia.technical/70038

Comment: Thanks for the link. That sucks. There is a ton a coding to do now. Thanks again. Guess I have to just close this question. But the way, I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I might be possible to monkey patch in the filter_var function what filters specifically are you looking to use?

Comment: I usually use Santize for url and validate for url and email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`filter_var` is now implemented in hhvm. Open github issues if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

This function appears to not have been implemented on HHVM  See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.linguistics.wikipedia.technical/70038

An option if you want to rely on this functionality with the hopes that it will enter the fold is to polyfill it in (partial implementation to inspire the motivated).

```
if (!function_exists("filter_var")){
      // define the constants used by the function 
      define("FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL", "email");

      function filter_var(){
          $args = func_get_args();
          // $args[1] is the filter type (second parameter)
          switch ($args[1]){
               case FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL:
                   if (preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $args[0])?$args[0]:false;
                   break;
          }
      }
}
```